# virtualboxでホストオンリーネットワークタブがない

Tags: virtualbox

ネットワーク関連初心者です。

virtualbox上でubuntuをゲストOSとして使用しています。
このubuntuのipアドレスを知りたいと思い、ifconfigコマンドで
調べようとしたのですが、192.168.**.**等が表示ませんでした。
そこで少し調べた結果、
https://qiita.com/amoO_O/items/ff1aa16bf1b60f34bb5d
を参考にipアドレスを付けよう?としたのですが
NATネットワークしかなく、ホストオンリーネットワークのタブがないため
困っております。

分かりやすくご教授いただければ幸いです。よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: 参考にされたページは3年前の記事なので、最新版(5.2.18)とは画面構成が異なります。可能であれば実際にお使いのバージョンも質問文に含めてもらうと良いかなと思います。

Comment: ご指摘ありがとうございます。現在使用中のものは最新の5.2.18でございます。

Answer (score 1):

ホストオンリーネットワークアダプタが未作成であれば、「ファイルメニュー」あるいは「グローバルツール」から「ホストネットワークマネージャー」を選択して、ホストオンリーネットワークアダプタを「作成」する必要があります。

作成した後は、仮想マシンの設定で「ネットワークアダプタ」の空きアダプタを有効化して「ホストオンリーアダプタ」を選択すれば、仮想マシンで利用可能になると思います。

Comment: 作成後空きアダプタを有効化し、「ホストオンリーアダプタ」を選択しました。しかしvirtualboxの「環境設定」、「ネットワーク」にはNATネットワークしか表示されておりません。これで使用可能でしょうか。

Comment: 仮想マシンの「詳細」の「ネットワーク」に「ホストオンリーアダプタ」が見えていれば使用可能です。ゲストOSから確認可能と思います。

Comment: ありがとうございました。確認できました。